# python module, global name no found.

Tags: python, module

It seems my python import ignores certain module!!
This is my filesystem structure:

```
dir1/
    dira/main.py
    dirb/dp.py, __init__.py
```

In dp.py, I have:

```
import itertools as it
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
....
def f():
    np.array.... # I use numpy here
    ...
```

I've changed the PYTHONPATH so that it can find dir1/. Now if I cd to dira/ and run ipython,

```
ipython
import dirb.dp as dp 
dp.
```

then I hit tab, it only shows:

```
dp.plt    dp.it   dp.f
```

but `dp.np` is not there!

in dira/main.py, I have:

```
import dirb.dp as dp
...
    dp.f()
```

and `dp.f()` uses numpy. 
Now if in ipython I run main.py, it errors and complaint that the global name np in dp.py is not defined.

I have no clue what is causing this problem. Any help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated !! 
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that it is importing an older version of your .py file which is missing the `import numpy as np` line? For example, if you had previously installed your module in /usr/lib (with something like setup.py). You can check where exactly it imported the module from with `my_module.__path__` and `my_module.__file__`.

Comment: very weird.... I left this problem unsolved last night, this morning I get up, and everything is fine now.....THanks for your input, helps me understand the importing system, at least I know what to do next time. Thanks again !

Comment: Does sound like it was reading from a different file. You might have set some environment variable wrong, which was not there anymore once you closed the terminal and checked it the second day.